# LeafletJS 0.8 in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, leaflet, internet-explorer-11

I implemented LeafletJS 0.8 in my application. This because of the many bugfixes I needed. However It seems that zooming is not working as expected in IE11

The leaflet is zooming out of its bounds, only in IE11

For a demo see here: http://robballou.com/j/leaflet.php?leaflet=8

Does anyone has an idea what could be happening here?

You do not have to provide valid code, just a point in the right direction would already be very helpful.

**Edit**: I just tested this on a Windows 7 machine and there are no problems there. It just happens on Windows 8 apparently

Comment: Tested given link in IE11 and didn't see anything strange regarding zooming. Can you provide, for example, screenshot of problem?

Comment: Edited the question because of your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this looks like an IE bug introduced when we added additional hardware accelerated composition in IE for Windows 8 and above.  Sorry about that!  I've filed a bug for us to investigate: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedbackdetail/view/1085713/transformed-elements-appear-outside-map-extents-in-leafletjs-win8-only

If during our investigation we find an easy workaround for you, I'll come back and post it here.